# Print dynamic selected checkbox using JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, jcheckbox

I'm new to `JFrame`, I was trying to populate dynamic checkboxes with a scroll pane. I tried with some code as seen below. My Focus is:

1. Get the selected dynamic checkbox's name.
2. While I click no (Radio button) the check box panel is set to disabled/frozen/uncheckable.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
public class JFrameMain extends JFrame {
  private JPanel contentPane;
  private JButton btnOkay;
  private JTextField textField;
  private JRadioButton yes;
  private JRadioButton no;
  // Launch the application.
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        try {
          JFrameMain frame = new JFrameMain();
          frame.setVisible(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  
   // Create the frame.
  public JFrameMain() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 556, 383);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Enetr the class", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    panel.setBounds(44, 23, 443, 53);
    contentPane.add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    
    yes = new JRadioButton("yes");
    yes.setSelected(true);
    yes.setBounds(144, 20, 64, 25);
    panel.add(yes);
    yes.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(yes.isSelected())
        {
          no.setSelected(false);
          textField.setEnabled(true);       
        }
      }
    });
    
    no = new JRadioButton("No");
    no.setBounds(212, 20, 64, 25);
    panel.add(no);
    no.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(no.isSelected())
        {
          yes.setSelected(false);
          textField.setEnabled(false);
        }
      }
    });
    
    btnOkay = new JButton("Okay");
    btnOkay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //Text field
        System.out.println(textField.getText());
      }
    });
    btnOkay.setBounds(120, 281, 97, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnOkay);
    
    JPanel panelCheckBox = new JPanel();
    panelCheckBox.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
    panelCheckBox.setBounds(44, 89, 443, 90);
    contentPane.add(panelCheckBox);
    panelCheckBox.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[]", "[]"));
    int numberCheckBox = 10;
    JCheckBox[] checkBoxList = new JCheckBox[numberCheckBox];

    for(int i = 0; i < numberCheckBox; i++) {
        checkBoxList[i] = new JCheckBox("CheckBox" + i);
        panelCheckBox.add(checkBoxList[i]);
    }
    JScrollBar scrollBar = new JScrollBar();
    scrollBar.setBounds(492, 89, 21, 90);
    contentPane.add(scrollBar);
    
    JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Enter Class", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    panel_1.setBounds(44, 192, 443, 66);
    contentPane.add(panel_1);
    panel_1.setLayout(null);
    
    textField = new JTextField();
    //textField.setEnabled(false);
    textField.setBounds(55, 23, 336, 22);
    panel_1.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);
   
    
    JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.exit(1);
      }
    });
    btnCancel.setBounds(263, 281, 97, 25);
    contentPane.add(btnCancel);
     }
}
```

I was stuck with this for the past 3 days. Can't get the selected checkbox name in dynamic checkboxes. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It is not recommended to use null layouts and set bounds manually. Instead, use [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) . Also when `yes` and `no` trigger each other endlessly,  That is why the GUI freezes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by having a look at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

One thing you want to focus on is the `setActionCommand` for buttons and `getActionCommand` for the `ActionEvent`

For example...

```
ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("You clicked " + e.getActionCommand());
    }
};

for (int i = 0; i < numberCheckBox; i++) {
    checkBoxList[i] = new JCheckBox("CheckBox" + i);
    panelCheckBox.add(checkBoxList[i]);
    checkBoxList[i].addActionListener(actionListener);
}
```

You're also going to want to take the time to read through [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Now, because it annoys me, the following is basically your design using proper layout managers

Yours...

[image]

Compared to mine...

[image]

And now you also have resisability for free

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(16, 16, 16, 16));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JTextField textField = new JTextField(40);

            JRadioButton yes = new JRadioButton("yes");
            yes.setSelected(true);
            yes.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (yes.isSelected()) {
                        textField.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
            });

            JRadioButton no = new JRadioButton("No");
            no.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (no.isSelected()) {
                        textField.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            });

            JPanel enterClassPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            enterClassPane.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Enetr the class", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
            enterClassPane.add(yes);
            enterClassPane.add(no);

            JPanel panelCheckBox = new JPanel(new WrapLayout(WrapLayout.LEADING));
            int numberCheckBox = 10;
            JCheckBox[] checkBoxList = new JCheckBox[numberCheckBox];

            for (int i = 0; i < numberCheckBox; i++) {
                checkBoxList[i] = new JCheckBox("CheckBox" + i);
                panelCheckBox.add(checkBoxList[i]);
                checkBoxList[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("You clicked " + e.getActionCommand());
                    }
                });
            }

            JPanel classPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            classPane.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Enter Class", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
            classPane.add(textField);

            JPanel actionsPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
            btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            });
            JButton btnOkay = new JButton("Okay");
            btnOkay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //Text field
                    System.out.println(textField.getText());
                }
            });
            actionsPane.add(btnOkay);
            actionsPane.add(btnCancel);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.gridwidth = gbc.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;

            add(enterClassPane, gbc);
            add(new JScrollPane(panelCheckBox), gbc);
            add(classPane, gbc);
            add(actionsPane, gbc);
        }
    }

    public class WrapLayout extends FlowLayout {

        private Dimension preferredLayoutSize;

        /**
         * Constructs a new <code>WrapLayout</code> with a left alignment and a
         * default 5-unit horizontal and vertical gap.
         */
        public WrapLayout() {
            super();
        }

        /**
         * Constructs a new <code>FlowLayout</code> with the specified alignment
         * and a default 5-unit horizontal and vertical gap. The value of the
         * alignment argument must be one of <code>WrapLayout</code>,
         * <code>WrapLayout</code>, or <code>WrapLayout</code>.
         *
         * @param align the alignment value
         */
        public WrapLayout(int align) {
            super(align);
        }

        /**
         * Creates a new flow layout manager with the indicated alignment and
         * the indicated horizontal and vertical gaps.
         * <p>
         * The value of the alignment argument must be one of
         * <code>WrapLayout</code>, <code>WrapLayout</code>, or
         * <code>WrapLayout</code>.
         *
         * @param align the alignment value
         * @param hgap the horizontal gap between components
         * @param vgap the vertical gap between components
         */
        public WrapLayout(int align, int hgap, int vgap) {
            super(align, hgap, vgap);
        }

        /**
         * Returns the preferred dimensions for this layout given the
         * <i>visible</i> components in the specified target container.
         *
         * @param target the component which needs to be laid out
         * @return the preferred dimensions to lay out the subcomponents of the
         * specified container
         */
        @Override
        public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container target) {
            return layoutSize(target, true);
        }

        /**
         * Returns the minimum dimensions needed to layout the <i>visible</i>
         * components contained in the specified target container.
         *
         * @param target the component which needs to be laid out
         * @return the minimum dimensions to lay out the subcomponents of the
         * specified container
         */
        @Override
        public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container target) {
            Dimension minimum = layoutSize(target, false);
            minimum.width -= (getHgap() + 1);
            return minimum;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the minimum or preferred dimension needed to layout the
         * target container.
         *
         * @param target target to get layout size for
         * @param preferred should preferred size be calculated
         * @return the dimension to layout the target container
         */
        private Dimension layoutSize(Container target, boolean preferred) {
            synchronized (target.getTreeLock()) {
                //  Each row must fit with the width allocated to the containter.
                //  When the container width = 0, the preferred width of the container
                //  has not yet been calculated so lets ask for the maximum.

                int targetWidth = target.getSize().width;
                Container container = target;

                while (container.getSize().width == 0 && container.getParent() != null) {
                    container = container.getParent();
                }

                targetWidth = container.getSize().width;

                if (targetWidth == 0) {
                    targetWidth = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                }

                int hgap = getHgap();
                int vgap = getVgap();
                Insets insets = target.getInsets();
                int horizontalInsetsAndGap = insets.left + insets.right + (hgap * 2);
                int maxWidth = targetWidth - horizontalInsetsAndGap;

                //  Fit components into the allowed width
                Dimension dim = new Dimension(0, 0);
                int rowWidth = 0;
                int rowHeight = 0;

                int nmembers = target.getComponentCount();

                for (int i = 0; i < nmembers; i++) {
                    Component m = target.getComponent(i);

                    if (m.isVisible()) {
                        Dimension d = preferred ? m.getPreferredSize() : m.getMinimumSize();

                        //  Can't add the component to current row. Start a new row.
                        if (rowWidth + d.width > maxWidth) {
                            addRow(dim, rowWidth, rowHeight);
                            rowWidth = 0;
                            rowHeight = 0;
                        }

                        //  Add a horizontal gap for all components after the first
                        if (rowWidth != 0) {
                            rowWidth += hgap;
                        }

                        rowWidth += d.width;
                        rowHeight = Math.max(rowHeight, d.height);
                    }
                }

                addRow(dim, rowWidth, rowHeight);

                dim.width += horizontalInsetsAndGap;
                dim.height += insets.top + insets.bottom + vgap * 2;

                //  When using a scroll pane or the DecoratedLookAndFeel we need to
                //  make sure the preferred size is less than the size of the
                //  target containter so shrinking the container size works
                //  correctly. Removing the horizontal gap is an easy way to do this.
                Container scrollPane = SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JScrollPane.class, target);

                if (scrollPane != null && target.isValid()) {
                    dim.width -= (hgap + 1);
                }

                return dim;
            }
        }

        /*
         *  A new row has been completed. Use the dimensions of this row
         *  to update the preferred size for the container.
         *
         *  @param dim update the width and height when appropriate
         *  @param rowWidth the width of the row to add
         *  @param rowHeight the height of the row to add
         */
        private void addRow(Dimension dim, int rowWidth, int rowHeight) {
            dim.width = Math.max(dim.width, rowWidth);

            if (dim.height > 0) {
                dim.height += getVgap();
            }

            dim.height += rowHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

[`WrapLayout`](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/)

> Actually I want this selected checkbox while I click OKAY Button

You have a number of possible options.  One might be to simply add or remove the "action command" of the checkbox from some kind of `List`

For example...

```
checkBoxList[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("You clicked " + e.getActionCommand());
        if (e.getSource() instanceof JCheckBox) {
            JCheckBox cb = (JCheckBox) e.getSource();
            if (cb.isSelected()) {
                selectedValues.add(cb.getActionCommand());
            } else {
                selectedValues.remove(cb.getActionCommand());
            }
        }
    }
});
```

### Runnable example

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Set<String> selectedValues = new HashSet<>(8);

        public TestPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(16, 16, 16, 16));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JTextField textField = new JTextField(40);

            JRadioButton yes = new JRadioButton("yes");
            yes.setSelected(true);
            yes.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (yes.isSelected()) {
                        textField.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
            });

            JRadioButton no = new JRadioButton("No");
            no.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (no.isSelected()) {
                        textField.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            });

            ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
            bg.add(yes);
            bg.add(no);

            JPanel enterClassPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            enterClassPane.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Enetr the class", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
            enterClassPane.add(yes);
            enterClassPane.add(no);

            JPanel panelCheckBox = new JPanel(new WrapLayout(WrapLayout.LEADING));
            int numberCheckBox = 10;
            JCheckBox[] checkBoxList = new JCheckBox[numberCheckBox];

            for (int i = 0; i < numberCheckBox; i++) {
                checkBoxList[i] = new JCheckBox("CheckBox" + i);
                panelCheckBox.add(checkBoxList[i]);
                checkBoxList[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("You clicked " + e.getActionCommand());
                        if (e.getSource() instanceof JCheckBox) {
                            JCheckBox cb = (JCheckBox) e.getSource();
                            if (cb.isSelected()) {
                                selectedValues.add(cb.getActionCommand());
                            } else {
                                selectedValues.remove(cb.getActionCommand());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            JPanel classPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            classPane.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Enter Class", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
            classPane.add(textField);

            JPanel actionsPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
            btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            });
            JButton btnOkay = new JButton("Okay");
            btnOkay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //Text field
                    System.out.println(textField.getText());

                    for (String command : selectedValues) {
                        System.out.println(command);
                    }
                }
            });
            actionsPane.add(btnOkay);
            actionsPane.add(btnCancel);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.gridwidth = gbc.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;

            add(enterClassPane, gbc);
            add(new JScrollPane(panelCheckBox), gbc);
            add(classPane, gbc);
            add(actionsPane, gbc);
        }
    }

    public class WrapLayout extends FlowLayout {

        private Dimension preferredLayoutSize;

        /**
         * Constructs a new <code>WrapLayout</code> with a left alignment and a
         * default 5-unit horizontal and vertical gap.
         */
        public WrapLayout() {
            super();
        }

        /**
         * Constructs a new <code>FlowLayout</code> with the specified alignment
         * and a default 5-unit horizontal and vertical gap. The value of the
         * alignment argument must be one of <code>WrapLayout</code>,
         * <code>WrapLayout</code>, or <code>WrapLayout</code>.
         *
         * @param align the alignment value
         */
        public WrapLayout(int align) {
            super(align);
        }

        /**
         * Creates a new flow layout manager with the indicated alignment and
         * the indicated horizontal and vertical gaps.
         * <p>
         * The value of the alignment argument must be one of
         * <code>WrapLayout</code>, <code>WrapLayout</code>, or
         * <code>WrapLayout</code>.
         *
         * @param align the alignment value
         * @param hgap the horizontal gap between components
         * @param vgap the vertical gap between components
         */
        public WrapLayout(int align, int hgap, int vgap) {
            super(align, hgap, vgap);
        }

        /**
         * Returns the preferred dimensions for this layout given the
         * <i>visible</i> components in the specified target container.
         *
         * @param target the component which needs to be laid out
         * @return the preferred dimensions to lay out the subcomponents of the
         * specified container
         */
        @Override
        public Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container target) {
            return layoutSize(target, true);
        }

        /**
         * Returns the minimum dimensions needed to layout the <i>visible</i>
         * components contained in the specified target container.
         *
         * @param target the component which needs to be laid out
         * @return the minimum dimensions to lay out the subcomponents of the
         * specified container
         */
        @Override
        public Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container target) {
            Dimension minimum = layoutSize(target, false);
            minimum.width -= (getHgap() + 1);
            return minimum;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the minimum or preferred dimension needed to layout the
         * target container.
         *
         * @param target target to get layout size for
         * @param preferred should preferred size be calculated
         * @return the dimension to layout the target container
         */
        private Dimension layoutSize(Container target, boolean preferred) {
            synchronized (target.getTreeLock()) {
                //  Each row must fit with the width allocated to the containter.
                //  When the container width = 0, the preferred width of the container
                //  has not yet been calculated so lets ask for the maximum.

                int targetWidth = target.getSize().width;
                Container container = target;

                while (container.getSize().width == 0 && container.getParent() != null) {
                    container = container.getParent();
                }

                targetWidth = container.getSize().width;

                if (targetWidth == 0) {
                    targetWidth = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                }

                int hgap = getHgap();
                int vgap = getVgap();
                Insets insets = target.getInsets();
                int horizontalInsetsAndGap = insets.left + insets.right + (hgap * 2);
                int maxWidth = targetWidth - horizontalInsetsAndGap;

                //  Fit components into the allowed width
                Dimension dim = new Dimension(0, 0);
                int rowWidth = 0;
                int rowHeight = 0;

                int nmembers = target.getComponentCount();

                for (int i = 0; i < nmembers; i++) {
                    Component m = target.getComponent(i);

                    if (m.isVisible()) {
                        Dimension d = preferred ? m.getPreferredSize() : m.getMinimumSize();

                        //  Can't add the component to current row. Start a new row.
                        if (rowWidth + d.width > maxWidth) {
                            addRow(dim, rowWidth, rowHeight);
                            rowWidth = 0;
                            rowHeight = 0;
                        }

                        //  Add a horizontal gap for all components after the first
                        if (rowWidth != 0) {
                            rowWidth += hgap;
                        }

                        rowWidth += d.width;
                        rowHeight = Math.max(rowHeight, d.height);
                    }
                }

                addRow(dim, rowWidth, rowHeight);

                dim.width += horizontalInsetsAndGap;
                dim.height += insets.top + insets.bottom + vgap * 2;

                //  When using a scroll pane or the DecoratedLookAndFeel we need to
                //  make sure the preferred size is less than the size of the
                //  target containter so shrinking the container size works
                //  correctly. Removing the horizontal gap is an easy way to do this.
                Container scrollPane = SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JScrollPane.class, target);

                if (scrollPane != null && target.isValid()) {
                    dim.width -= (hgap + 1);
                }

                return dim;
            }
        }

        /*
         *  A new row has been completed. Use the dimensions of this row
         *  to update the preferred size for the container.
         *
         *  @param dim update the width and height when appropriate
         *  @param rowWidth the width of the row to add
         *  @param rowHeight the height of the row to add
         */
        private void addRow(Dimension dim, int rowWidth, int rowHeight) {
            dim.width = Math.max(dim.width, rowWidth);

            if (dim.height > 0) {
                dim.height += getVgap();
            }

            dim.height += rowHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Really Thank you so much for the valuable answer Mr. Mad Programmer, It working and I can get the selected checkboxes. Actually I want this selected checkbox while I click OKAY Button. I tried with " System.out.println("You clicked " + e.getActionCommand());" in button action performed, its not working. Could you please help me solve this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @vinoth Check the update

Comment: thank you so much. Its working. I'll try to get the output for remaining thing, like **1. when I select yes radio button text box should goto editable mode and checkbox panel should in unEnabled mode**. Same as **2. When I select No radio button Checkbox panel should be enabled and Textbox should be unEnable mode.**

Comment: Sure, you have array of checkboxes, you could start by loppingnof it and updating the enabled state of the check boxes

Comment: Hello Mr. Mad Programmer, I tried a lot to disable the checkbox panel while **Yes**Radio button selected. but its not working for me. **1.** When **"Yes" radio button** selected **Checkbox panel** should be **disabled** and **textbox** want to  **enabled**. **2.** When **"No" Radio button ** selected **Checkbox panel** should be **enabled** and **textbox**should be **disabled** could you please help me with this, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using null layouts and setting bounds manually, I would suggest using a combination of basic layout managers for the job. 
Note the comments and the use of `ButtonGroup` for the `JRadioButton`s:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class JFrameMain extends JFrame {
    private final JPanel contentPane;
    private final JButton btnOkay;
    private JTextField textField = null;
    private final JRadioButton yes;
    private final JRadioButton no;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                JFrameMain frame = new JFrameMain();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    public JFrameMain() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(); //use the default FlowLayoyt
        panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Enetr the class", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
        contentPane.add(panel);

        yes = new JRadioButton("yes");
        yes.setSelected(true);
        panel.add(yes);
        yes.addActionListener(e -> {
            if(yes.isSelected()) {
              textField.setEnabled(true);
            }
          });

        no = new JRadioButton("No");
        panel.add(no);
        no.addActionListener(e -> {
            if(no.isSelected())         {
              textField.setEnabled(false);
            }
          });

        //for the required functionality add the radio buttons to ButtonGroup
        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
        bg.add(yes);  bg.add(no);

        JPanel panelCheckBox = new JPanel();
        panelCheckBox.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
        contentPane.add(panelCheckBox); //or  contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(panelCheckBox));

        contentPane.add(panelCheckBox);
        panelCheckBox.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 4, 5, 5)); //GridLayout is a better choice for mre than MigLayout
        int numberCheckBox = 10;
        JCheckBox[] checkBoxList = new JCheckBox[numberCheckBox];

        for(int i = 0; i < numberCheckBox; i++) {
            JCheckBox cb  = new JCheckBox("CheckBox" + i);
            panelCheckBox.add(cb);
            cb.addActionListener(e->System.out.println(cb.getText() +" selected"));
            checkBoxList[i] = cb;
        }

        JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();//use the default FlowLayoyt
        panel_1.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Enter Class", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
        contentPane.add(panel_1);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setColumns(40);
        panel_1.add(textField);

        JPanel buttonspane = new JPanel(); //use a panel with the default FlowLayoyt for the buttons
        contentPane.add(buttonspane);
        btnOkay = new JButton("Okay");
        btnOkay.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println(textField.getText()));
        buttonspane.add(btnOkay);

        JButton btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        btnCancel.addActionListener(e -> System.exit(1));
        buttonspane.add(btnCancel);

        pack();
    }
}
```